# Automatically saving relationships when creating models with Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I seem to be stumped on how to automatically save related models when *creating* a model instance in Laravel. Consider:

A User Model:

```
<?php
// file: User.php
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function role()
    {
        $this->hasOne('Role');
    }
}
```

A Role Model:

```
<?php
// file: Role.php
class Role extends Eloquent
{
    public function user()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Now lets say I want to create a new user and assign a it a role. Its quite easy to get the association to work if I set the role relationship *after* I save the user. For example, this works great:

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = 'Bobby';
$user->save();

$role = new Role();
$role->type = "Super Hero";
$user->role()->save($role);
```

However, if I want to `push` or `cascade` the save it fails to assign the foreignKey. I'd like to `save()` only once, and have the relationships save via cascade. For example, this doesn't work:

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = 'Bobby';

$role = new Role();
$role->type = "Super Hero";

$user->role = $role;   // or $user->role()->save($role);
$user->save();         // push()?
```

This would be somewhat similar to how Doctrine 2 handles `persisting`. Is it possible to *create* both at the same time in Eloquent?

Comment: having the same question, any update so far?